# UIBezierPath of a circle and rectangle intersection for a mask

Tags: objective-c, uibezierpath

I am trying to create a mask region of the intersection of a circle and a rectangle.

I am starting with this code that seems to create an XOR of the circle and rectangle for the mask region but I want just a plain old AND:

```
- (void)addMaskToHoleViewAtX:(CGFloat) x AtY:(CGFloat) y Radius:(CGFloat) kRadius {
   CGRect bounds = holeView.bounds;
   CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
   maskLayer.frame = bounds;
   maskLayer.fillColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;

   CGRect const rect = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMidX(bounds) - kRadius/2,
                                  CGRectGetMidY(bounds) - kRadius,
                                  kRadius,
                                  2 * kRadius);
   UIBezierPath *pathrect = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:rect];

   CGRect const circ = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMidX(bounds) - kRadius,
                                  CGRectGetMidY(bounds) - kRadius,
                                  2 * kRadius,
                                  2 * kRadius);
   UIBezierPath *pathcirc= [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:circ];

   UIBezierPath *allPaths= [[UIBezierPath alloc] init];
   [allPaths appendPath:pathrect];
   [allPaths appendPath:pathcirc];
   [allPaths appendPath:[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:bounds]];

   maskLayer.path = allPaths.CGPath;
   maskLayer.fillRule = kCAFillRuleEvenOdd;

   holeView.layer.mask = maskLayer;
   holeView.center = CGPointMake(x, y);
}
```

Could someone help me with the syntax to do the AND, I think I might need to use addClip but it is not obvious to me how to do that with the above code?

MY SOLUTION: It appears to me that if I were able to figure how to use addClip to solve this problem in one manner, I would not actually end up with the closed NSBezierPath of the intersection.  I prefer not to do it that way as having the intersection NSBezierPath is also needed to easily determine if a point is inside the path.  SOOOO, I just created the NSBezierPath of the intersection through calculations and used my derived path to append to the masklayer bounds path.  It sure would be nice to have a way of actually obtaining the intersection NSBezierPath without calculations but I just had to move on.  Thanks for trying.

Thanks,
Carmen

EDIT : Here is the routine I am calling to put the 'intersection' mask over my _map View.  Change _map to your view if you want to try this:

```
- (void)addHoleSubview {
   holeView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10000, 10000)];
   holeView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255 green:0 blue:0 alpha:0.2];
   holeView.autoresizingMask = 0;
   [_map addSubview:holeView];
   [self addMaskToHoleViewAtX:100 AtY:100 Radius:50];
}
```

Comment: Could you draw a picture of what you're after? What does the "intersection of a circle and a rectangle" look like?

Comment: At first glance I would say that the XOR behaviour is because you are using `kCAFillRuleEvenOdd` on the mask layer

Comment: Hi matt, the intersection varies according to relative positions.  The position I have coded should result in an arced top and bottom with two vertical sides.

Comment: David, I think that kCAFillRuleEvenOdd is needed to result in a mask at all, this intersection I am trying to obtain is subtracted from the mask layer to give a clear window to the view below, Carmen

Comment: I don't see why what you've written would give "an arced top and bottom with two vertical sides". If the circle is larger than the square, the resulting path is the circle - all sides would be rounded. If you don't want the sides of the circle, it is up to you not to draw the sides of the circle in the first place.

Comment: When I run my coded example I get what I described with, what I thought was taken for granted, both arches having the same center point since both arches are part of the original circle, try it.

Comment: Clarification, the result of my coded example would be what I described IF it would give the AND not the XOR.

Answer (score 0):

If you aim for the intersection of two paths you should not create a compound path. Appending a path to another path will

- result in a **union** of both paths if using the non-zero winding number rule and both paths have the same direction - or in other words it will have the effect of an `AND`
- result in a shape that contains only the parts of the areas surrounded by the two paths that do not overlap if using the even-odd rule - or in other words it will have the effect of an `XOR`.

Instead I suggest you first add the first path `pathrect` to your graphics context and clip

```
[pathrect addClip];
```

and then you add the second path `pathcirc` to your context and clip again:

```
[pathcirc addClip];
```

You can now use any filling rule within that context and it will fill the **intersection** (the `AND`) of the two paths.

Comment: There's only one path already - it's a compound path, but it's just one path.

Comment: Thanks, Mischa, I am sure you have given me the answer but I can not figure out what my graphics context is here, is it the masklayer? I have tried addClips everywhere so I think I am just not understanding the process.  Do I set the holeView.layer.mask more than once? Carmen

Comment: @Carm100: Actually I am not sure if I have given you the answer. I just thought it might help or give a hint in the right direction. My suggested method works great for 'real drawing' i.e. when you have a graphics context. Then you can easily crop the whole context with any path using `[path addClip]` and afterwards fill the path with any color. But what you need is not only a cropped shape but a 'real' cropped path so you can use that particular path as a layer mask. And I must admit that after some research I still haven't found a way to achieve that.

Comment: @matt: You are right. I was a little sloppy with my formulation. I have updated my answer.